# NodeJS запрос fetch. Получить данные с файла

Tags: json, node.js, файлы

В файле app.js у меня есть fetch запрос

```
fetch('http://localhost/users')
  .then(function (response) {
    response.json().then(function (data) {
      console.log('data', data);
    });
  });
```

В файле server.js  я обрабатываю запрос

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  /*
    На данном маршруте нужно вывести содержимое файла users.dat
  */
  fs.readFile("users.data", "utf8",
    function (error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    });
});
```

Мне не удается вернуть содержимое файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На клиенте всё в порядке.
На сервере вы читайте файл, осталось только его отправить.

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {
  /*
    На данном маршруте нужно вывести содержимое файла users.dat
  */
  fs.readFile("users.data", "utf8",
    function (error, data) {
      if (error) throw error;
      res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
});
```

Comment: Или просто `res.json(data);`